# Make an infinite scroll with react and ruby-graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I trying to make an infinite scroll with `react-infinite-scroll-component`. The problem that I have is how to fetch the data using Apollo client for ruby-graphQl

This is what I tried. But it's not reaching de Query to even know if the logic works. How can I make it work?

```
class Users extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: { users: [] },
    cursor: 0
  };

  fetchMoreData = () => {
    console.log("until here works");

    return (
      <Query
        query={get_users}
        variables={{ limit: 9, skip: cursor }}
        fetchPolicy="cache-and-network"
      >
        {({ data }) => {
          console.log("never reached this point");

          return this.setState({
            items: data,
            cursor: cursor + 9
          });
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  };

  render() {
    this.fetchMoreData();
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (
       <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={items.users.length}
        next={this.fetchMoreData}
        hasMore
        loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
      >
         <UsersList items={items} />
      </InfiniteScroll>
    );
  }
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move commented line:

```
  render() {
    this.fetchMoreData(); // move this line from here to `componentWillMount`
    const { items } = this.state;
```

componentWillMount will fetch the data and

```
componentWillMount(){
   this.fetchMoreData();
}
```

Also, You need to push into array not set it.
1st of all, make sure what kind of `data` you are getting from `Query`
then `concat` to your array.

```
return this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.concat( data ) //make sure yr data is properly concatenate!
      cursor: cursor + 9
});
```